# AUC ROC and Varying Thresholds?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, roc, threshold

I understand that the ROC curve will plot the sensitivity vs FPR for varying thresholds.

For my SVM ML model, I desire a good sensitivity score so I have decreased the threshold to make a positive classification to 0.40. I know this threshold will increase the sensitivity but decrease the PPV and specificity.

The AUCROC for the default threshold SVM model is much higher (AUROC = 0.80) than the AUROC for the SVM model with the adjusted threshold of 0.40 (AUROC = 0.73).

This does not make sense to me because the ROC curve is a plot of the sensitivity vs FPR for varying thresholds. Shouldn't the ROC Curve and AUROC score be identical between the default svm model and the svm model with threshold = 0.40.

Or is it that I don't correctly understand what the ROC curve is plotting?

Here is the code I used:

prob_preds = clf.predict_proba(x_test)

threshold = 0.40
preds = [1 if prob_preds[i][1] > threshold else 0 for i in range(len(prob_preds))]

fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, preds)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you've created binary predictions and then constructed the ROC curve. This is not the same as using continuous-valued predictions and constructing a ROC curve.

Comment: Yes everything you wrote is correct. I have even added the code that I used to my question above. So if I constructed the ROC curve using continuous value predictions (like svc.decision_function(X_test)) how would that differ than constructing a ROC curve using binary predictions?

Comment: For fixed labels and predictions, predictions will have the same ROC curve. Same data in, same curve out. But thresholding the data changes the predictions, so the resulting ROC curve will depend on the choice of threshold. All ROC curves visualize the TPR/FPR tradeoff. But using the discrete data gives a less informative curve because there are only 2 predicted values.

Comment: Thank you Sycorax. Therefore, if I want to obtain high sensitivity scores, I can threshold the model to be more liberal in predicting the positive data class and only use those adjusted predictions to construct the confusion matrix. However when I construct ROC curves I should always use continuous valued predictions that are completely uninfluenced by thresholding (than the ROC curve will be the same all the time I assume). Is this all correct Sycorax?

Comment: @chris when you set preds as binary, you are saying that your model was absolutely certain about the predictions. You need to pass the prediction probabilities to calculate the correct FPR and TPR for the thresholds.

Comment: @ping yes I understand that now. So in order to build ROC curves I should always use prediction probabilities. And if I want to obtain a higher sensitivity for my model, I can  adjust the threshold, and use the adjusted threshold and adjusted predictions to make my confusion matrix?

Comment: @chris yes. Then you can choose the threshold that optimizes the performances you need and get the final confusion matrix based on that binarization.